# Rscript producing empty plot inside true if statement

Tags: r

If I run the following Rscript below, I get a corrupt blank PDF containing nothing. However, if I comment out the if statement I get a PDF. Even when the if statement is not commented out, I still see `null device 1` in stdout:

```
ifiddes@ifiddes-desktop ~ $ Rscript test.R
[1] 3
null device 
         1
```

Here is the example script with the if statements active

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(lattice)

d <- matrix(c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9), nrow=3, ncol=3)

myPanel <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
    panel.levelplot(x, y, z, ...)
    panel.text(x, y, 100 * round(exp(-z),4))
}

if ( dim(d)[1] > 0 ) {

pdf()
print(dim(d)[1], stdout())
levelplot(as.matrix(-log(d)), main="", xlab="Read bases", ylab="Reference bases", panel = myPanel, col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256))

dev.off()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `lattice`, you must explicitly `print` your plot to the device.

```
if ( dim(d)[1] > 0 ) {
  pdf()
  print(dim(d)[1], stdout())
  myplot <- levelplot(as.matrix(-log(d)), main="", xlab="Read bases", ylab="Reference bases", panel = myPanel, col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256))
  print(myplot) # Use print() to save your plot.
  dev.off()
}
```